# shared_timed_mutex is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, c++14

I am running on MacOs Sierra `10.12.6` with Xcode9. As per Apple `#include <shared_mutex>` is available in MacOS 10.12.

But trying to include gives me error saying

> `shared_timed_mutex` is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12

Comment: cannot reproduce in `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)` did you remember to `-std=c++14` ?

Comment: `CONFIG += c++14` is present